# How to get the current date using php

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I am having trouble to get my current date of my system to compare it under my sql statement.

This is my sql statement:

```
    $sql = "SELECT event_registrant.eventID, event_registrant.userID, eventTitle, enddate FROM event_registrant 
LEFT JOIN hotel_event ON event_registrant.eventID = hotel_event.eventID 
LEFT JOIN users ON event_registrant.userID = users.userID WHERE enddate > " . date("Y/m/d");
```

Actually I want to compare my enddate with my currentdate and do some processing through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should Always use mysql function doing SQL operations , Ask me , I faced lots of issues.

```
    $sql = "SELECT event_registrant.eventID, event_registrant.userID, eventTitle, enddate FROM event_registrant 
LEFT JOIN hotel_event ON event_registrant.eventID = hotel_event.eventID 
LEFT JOIN users ON event_registrant.userID = users.userID WHERE enddate > CURDATE()";
```

Notice use of `CURDATE()`.

**EDIT**

use `hotel_event.enddate` at the end instead of plain `enddate` , I hope enddate is of table hotel_event . If there are  more than 1 table , always use Alias table name.

Comment: @yosemite use now() instead of curdate().

Comment: @yosemite , if it solved issue , you can upvote ( Up Arrow). Please let us know what was issue and what did you do to solve it ? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Make changes

```
$sql = "SELECT event_registrant.eventID, event_registrant.userID, eventTitle, enddate FROM event_registrant 
LEFT JOIN hotel_event ON event_registrant.eventID = hotel_event.eventID 
LEFT JOIN users ON event_registrant.userID = users.userID WHERE enddate > CURDATE()";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use now() in mysql instead of php function

Answer (score 0):

You must change the date format, date('Y/m/d') => date('Y-m-d')

```
$sql = "SELECT event_registrant.eventID, event_registrant.userID, eventTitle,    enddate FROM event_registrant 
LEFT JOIN hotel_event ON event_registrant.eventID = hotel_event.eventID 
LEFT JOIN users ON event_registrant.userID = users.userID WHERE enddate > " . date("Y-m-d");
```